# Geometry on Latitude/Longitude (Projection of point on arc)

Tags: javascript, math, latitude-longitude

I just want to check if there is a point (lat, long) of the projection intersecting with the arc giving by 2 points (lat, long) and if it does, I want to find that (lat, long).

Can (lat, long) be used as a 2D vector space to make this problem similar to the one in cartesian co-ordinates? How accurate would it be?

While the answer on [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171230114759/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51785.html) helps with getting the distance to the arc, how can I know whether the point of intersection is between the points that were used to find the great circle? Also would it be possible to solve this without having to use switch to cartesian co-ordinates?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this.

The first assumes a straight line between the two points--although, in actuality, such a line would intersect with the earth.

The second actually determines the great-circle route between the two points, that is, the minimum-length arc that actually follows the earth's surface and joins the two points.  To do this, you have to use coordinate transformations to generate vectors of direction cosines for the two superficial points.  Call them A and B.

To determine whether C lies on that arc, you can't just do linear interpolation like you could if you cheated and used a line segment that passes through the earth.  Instead, you need to calculate the direction cosines for C also.  C lies true between A and B if angles AC, BC, and AB are all equal.  Angles can be determined by calculating the dot products of the corresponding direction cosines and evaluating the inverse cosine thereof.

Comment: The question was to determine the equivalent of an 'orthogonal projection' of a point that i know is not on the arc. So C would be a point that does not lie on the arc but point D, which marks the intersection of the two great circles does (the second one being the arc that joins C and D). I also want to know if D lies on the major arc joining A and B or not